# Why the execution time is different in visual studio than browserstack? How can I fix it?

Tags: c#, selenium, automated-tests, browserstack

I am running a test with the Test Explorer in Visual Studio C# and it returns a timeout and the execution time is 30 seconds(I specified that time) but in browserstack is almost 2 minutes. How can I change the 90 seconds idle timeout in browserstack in order to finish the test in Visual studio and browserstack at the same time? This is giving me issues because I have to much tests in the queue and I am reaching the limit of my account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're asking for how to increase the default timeout of the webdriver.

```
Driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(90);
Driver.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(90);
```

The above code with change the maximum time the driver will wait for the page to load and the maximum time the driver will wait while finding an element. This is assuming your IWebDriver object is named 'Driver.

Comment: I took the advice and put the same time than browserstack is using for idle timeout.